# Char incompatible with string

Tags: java, string, encryption, char

I have to create a program that decrypts the message `:mmZ\dxZmx]Zpgy`
the encryption method is ASCII code. 
This should be all that I need but im getting an incompatible type error
here:

```
char encrypted[]= "(:mmZ\\dxZmx]Zpgy)";
```

I know that technically its a string but I couldn't think of any other way of doing this..
here is my entire code

```
package decrypt;

public class Decrypt 
{
    public static void decrypt(char encrypted[], int key)
    {
        System.out.println(key + ": ");
        for (int i=0; i < encrypted.length; i++)
        {
            char originalChar = encrypted[i];
            char encryptedChar;
            if ((originalChar -key) < 32)
                encryptedChar = (char) (originalChar - 32 + 127 -key);
            else 
                encryptedChar = (char) (originalChar -key);
            System.out.println(encryptedChar);
        }    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        char encrypted[]= "(:mmZ\\dxZmx]Zpgy)";    
        for (int i=1; i <=100; i++)
        {
            decrypt(encrypted, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> String a char array.

char array should consists of individual char elements. Not a whole string.

```
  char encrypted[]= "(:mmZ\\dxZmx]Zpgy)";
```

should be either

```
char encrypted[]= {'(',':',.....remaining elements ..};
```

or easily

```
   char encrypted[]= "(:mmZ\\dxZmx]Zpgy)".toCharArray();
```

Comment: @caustr01 No issues. Happens to every programmer. happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

`"(:mmZ\\dxZmx]Zpgy)"` is a String.

To convert it to `charArray`, use:

```
char encrypted[] = "(:mmZ\\dxZmx]Zpgy)".toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your have to add toCharArray cause this is a string and you want char array

```
char encrypted[]= "(:mmZ\\dxZmx]Zpgy)".toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Gave it a quick look ,you might use

```
"(:mmZ\\dxZmx]Zpgy)".toCharArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array of character but assigning the string to it.It will give you error but if you create a string just and pass it as argument to the method then your method would look like this

```
public static void decrypt(String encrypted,int key){
System.out.println(key + ": ");
for (int i=0; i < encrypted.length; i++){
    char originalChar = encrypted.CharAt(i);
    char encryptedChar;
    if ((originalChar -key) < 32)
        encryptedChar = (char) (originalChar - 32 + 127 -key);
    else 
        encryptedChar = (char) (originalChar -key);
    System.out.println(encryptedChar);

}

}
```